# redirecting to URL based on user's id (ex. /todo/{id})

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm making todo app with springboot.

---

*What I want to solve*

After login, **I want the user to redirect 'todolist' page URL based on his user's id.**(ex, localhost:8080/todo/{id})

I supposed to redirect to URL based on one's id, but page redirects not to localhost:8080/todo/{id}, but localhost:8080.

Of course, there is a id column in user DB.

---

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
@Lazy
private UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService;

@GetMapping("/login")
public String showLoginPage() {
    return "login";
}

@GetMapping("/signup")
public String showUserRegistration(@ModelAttribute("signupForm") SignupForm signupForm) {
    return "signup";
}

@PostMapping("/signup")
public String userRegistration(@Validated @ModelAttribute("signupForm") SignupForm signupForm, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "signup";
    }
    userRegistrationService.userRegistration(signupForm.getEmail(), signupForm.getPassword());
    return "redirect:/login";
}
}
```

---

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin(login -> login
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/todo")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .permitAll())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
            .mvcMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );
    http.logout().permitAll();
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

---

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "authority")
private String authority;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<>();

public User(String email, String password, String authority) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.authority = authority;
}

public User() {

}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}

public void setAuthority(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}

public List<Todo> getTodos() {
    return todos;
}

public void setTodos(List<Todo> todos) {
    this.todos = todos;
}
}
```

---

*What I tried*
I added  '/todo/{id}' to defaultSeccessUrl, but nothing changed.

To sum up, **I want the user to redirect to todolist page URL based on user's id**

Does anyone help?
I would appreciate　if you cloud answered to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the argument of defaultSuccessUrl as follows

```
defaultSuccessUrl("/redirector")
```

and add the following to your controller:

```
@GetMapping("/redirector")
public String redirector() {
    // load the user from the session or SecurityContext
    return "redirect:/todo/" + user.getId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I tried the way but it redirected to '/todo'. This means I can't get the user's information after login?

Comment: You can get user in Spring with User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() but there may be an issue in your code resulting in user not being stored as the authentication principal.